# Catch session expiration in Flask

Tags: python, flask

In Flask I'm using app.permanent_session_lifetime to force a session timeout. Is there a way to receive a callback before the session expires so I can perform cleanup? Looking through the documentation I don't see a corresponding Signal.

Comment: By default Flask's sessions are not reaped because they are backed by a cookie.  The reaping is handled by the browser, which doesn't send the cookie if it is expired.  Are you using the default session backing or are you using a custom one?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm going to investigate using server-side sessions with Flask-KVSession instead.