# How to run a function on session ends in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I want to be a able to run a function once a user's session ends( they either close the browser or it times out).

How would I go about doing this?

```
#create timeout
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)

#run function once session ends
#@app.session_ends
def session_ended()
    #run code
```

Comment: Does it token based?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

In `@app.before_request` check whether session is globally active or not by using something like `g`. After that call for the action you need.

```
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = None
    if 'user' in session:
        g.user = session['user']
    else:
        session_ended()
```

Comment: This answer seems to run session_ended() ONLY if a request is sent to it after the session expires. How would it run the function if a request is not sent after expiration?

Comment: To my knowledge in front end technologies there is no way to know the session expiration until you make a request to the backend. Even here until we make a request there is no known method to identify the session is dusted or not. If you really want to do something like that use a timer, when the timer is go off trigger the function.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way HTTP sessions work, there is simply no reliable way to do this.

Think more about what problem you're trying to solve and find another way to do it than running a function when a session expires.

Comment: I tend to prefer this response because I think that it briefly summarises the core of the problem, and the suggestion is most probably a very good advice - 'rethink'. However, depending on the particular case, the other responses by e.g. @G-Shenoy are also useful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the flask is cookie based, and you don't have a callback option available. But if of help following are some pointers.

[Call a function when Flask session expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707367/call-a-function-when-flask-session-expires)

[Catch session expiration in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449819/catch-session-expiration-in-flask)

https://www.google.com/amp/s/pythonawesome.com/flask-user-session-management/amp/

**Edit**

One possibility could be to run some timer or scheduler, check and invalidate the session, would say kind of hack, not a clean solution.

Comment: the answer in these links seem to run the function ONLY if a request is sent to it after the session expires. How would it run the function if a request is not sent after expiration?

Comment: As I mentioned above and understand, there is no such possibilities. One thing could be to run some timer or scheduler, check and invalidate the session.